# GRASS report list of parcel values

Tags: grass-gis, reports

Is there a way to get a report of the values of every land parcel on a raster map layer?

In the same way r.report can be used to find how large the parcels are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first run [r.clump](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.clump.html) to generate a map of individual parcel IDs. Then [r.stats.zonal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.stats.zonal.html), using that new map as cover map to perform the zonal statistics or [r.report](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.report.html).